# How to execute CMD command on jenkins windows agent using groovy?

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-agent

I am trying to execute `cmd /c echo hello` using groovy on a jenkins agent running on windows.

Here is my groovy:

```
node('WINDOWS-AGENT-1') {
    def cmd_command = "cmd /c echo hello"
    cmd_command.execute()
}
```

And I can see in the job logs that it is indeed running on that windows agent: **'Running on WINDOWS-AGENT-1'**

But I get an error: `java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`

And if I try to run linux like `ls -l` it works fine. Shows me the files of my Jenkins controller.

How can I execute this CMD command on my Windows Jenkins agent from my groovy script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to execute a command on a given node, you need to use one of the Jenkins Pipeline's steps designed to execute shell scripts (e.g. `sh` or `bat`). You need to be aware that any Groovy code in your Jenkinsfile is always executed on the **`master`** node:

> *"1. Except for the steps themselves, all of the Pipeline logic, the Groovy conditionals, loops, etc execute on the master. Whether simple or complex! Even inside a `node` block!"*
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/#fundamentals</sup>

```groovy
node('WINDOWS-SLAVE-1') {
    bat "cmd /c echo hello"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the 'bat'/'sh' options but I wanted to define a Process object using that execution of the command [e.g def proc = cmd_command.execute()] to control the output, exit code etc.. I didn't know that every groovy command is executed on the master so thanks for clearing that out for me.

Comment: @Szymon Stepniak do you mind to have a look on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66999465/how-to-run-long-msbuild-command-in-groovy-file-in-windows-slave