# How to run long msbuild command in groovy file in windows slave

Tags: windows, groovy, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below `msbuild` deploy command which is working local:

```
msbuild "Database Services\Database Services.sqlproj" /t:deploy /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=TEST,111;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False /p:TargetDatabase="test_db"
```

what is correct syntax to run it in jenkisfile.groovy?
I'm running against my windows machine, so I guess it should start with `bat "msbuild ......."`

I tried many syntax but they all failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise to go multiline then, to have more flexibility and freedom

```groovy
bat (
    label: 'Run Tests',
    script: """
        set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Pipeline
        dotnet test
        if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1
    """
)
```

Note that for multiline you have to keep track of exit code of every line, so while it is not necessary here, you can split your other lines by this to make sure build stops on a first failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
bat ' msbuild "Database Services\\Database Services.sqlproj" /t:deploy /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=TEST,111;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False /p:TargetDatabase="test_db" '
```